# Clarification on Teaching Prep definition

Tags: teaching

So my question is say you are teaching 3 Health 101 classes... one is a regular 15 week class in a classroom... one is an online section and one is an accelerated online 8 week class would this be considered 1 prep... 2 preps or even 3 preps as they are all 3 Health classes but all are somewhat different in what would need to be done and when.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official definition of teaching prep.